# ORACLE_HOME Error 6 initializing in Windows

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem with `ORALCE_HOME` when I try to start it using `sqlplus`. The output is this:

```
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

I've tried this command, but it doesn't work:

```
set PATH=c:\oracle\ora92\bin;%PATH%
set ORALCE_HOME=c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\sqlplus
```

Is there anyone who can help me please?

Comment: Which version of the client did you install? You mention 9.2 in your PATH, but your oracle home mentions 11.2. P.S. Did you typo ORACLE_HOME here, or is that what you actually used? If so, correct the typo and try again?

Comment: @Boneist    I installed oracle 11g  I didn't understand what typo ??

Comment: you said `set ORALCE_HOME`, the error message tells you to `set ORACLE_HOME`. Do you see that you've transposed the C and the L of ORACLE?

Comment: ohh Thank U I was stupied I didn't notice that

Answer (score 4):

In your case **ORACLE_HOME** should be: `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server`

You can try the following commands:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\sqlplus
```

Comment: The msb file can be found in folder %ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\mesg. you need to set its value as "..server", or "...92"

Comment: could you tell me please step by step what i should do exactly